# Saving a canvas in a bitmap and then Using that Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have a canvas:

```
Canvas c=null;
```

and a loop that draws a rect, because I change the position of the rect every loop, the rect will move on the screen.

```
int i=0;
while(isRunning){
   i++;
   c=null;
   Paint p=new Paint();
   p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
   c.drawRect(i,i,i+5,i+5,p);
}
```

I want to create a backgorund, for this example(a big blue rect over all screen):

```
   Paint backgroundP=new Paint();
   backgroundP.setColor(Color.BLUE);
   c.DrawRect(view.getLeft(),view.getTop(),view.getRight().view.getBottom(),backgroundP);
```

the background is created before the loop(before i create the rect that moves).

now what i want to do is to save the canvas with the background(the big blue rect) on a bitmap, and then in the loop to draw the small rect that moves over the bitmap-so it will draw the rect,which will move and it will draw the background (so there will be the rect that moves and a background)

How do I save a canvas on a bitmap and then draw that bitmap on the canvas that in the loop?

if you don't mind, posting a code that does what I described in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to draw a rect on a plain-colored background you could try this:

```
private Paint rectPaint = new Paint();
private Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 5, 5);

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, rectPaint);
}
```

This code does not move your rect yet. You could use the following method to add an offset to the previously defined rect, thus moving it on the canvas.

```
public void moveRect(int dx,int dy){
    rect.offset(dx, dy);
}
```

Where exactly this should happen depends on the rest of your code. (Maybe each time onDraw() is called?)

If your aim is to draw different bitmaps on a canvas you should try this method

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, left, top, paint);
```

For this you can either load the bitmap from a resource:

```
Bitmap backgroundBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context,
            R.drawable.your_background_bitmap);
```

or initialize an empty Bitmap and draw to this bitmap using a Canvas:

```
Bitmap backgroundBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(),
            Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas backgroundCanvas = new Canvas(backgroundBitmap);
backgroundCanvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
```

If you have more information on what your code is about (e.g. a custom View, a game loop) I could help you with more precise answers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't save the canvas to a bitmap, you make the canvas write to a bitmap from the beginning.

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

That will make the canvas write to an in memory bitmap. Then just use that canvas to draw on.

Comment: but doesnt it change the bitmap every round of the loop? I mean that it will save not just the background but also the rect that moves every rouud of the loop? so instead of moving the rect, it will replicate it?